# Integrating the player velocity to the camera rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a camera that follows a player and rotates around it with mouse input. I would like to know how can I add a lighter rotation to the camera depending of the players velocity in addition of the rotation from the mouse.

I have this code but I'm not sure what to put after "Input.GetAxis("MouseX")" :

```
void UpdatePosition()
{
    Debug.Log(playerScript.velocity);

    lookHorizontal = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("MouseX") /* + some additional rotation */, -10000, 10000);
    lookVertical = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("MouseY") /* + some additional rotation */, -10000, 10000);

    if (lookHorizontal > global.joystickDeadZone || lookHorizontal < -global.joystickDeadZone)
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(lookHorizontal / (1 / global.lookSensitivity * 100), Vector3.up) * offset;
    }
    if (lookVertical > global.joystickDeadZone || lookVertical < -global.joystickDeadZone)
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(lookVertical / (1 / global.lookSensitivity * 100), -this.transform.right) * offset;
    }
    this.transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(this.transform.position, playerRealPosition + offset, positionLerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by add a lighter rotation depending on velocity? Can you give 2 examples?

Comment: In GTA 5, you can move the player and you can also rotate the camera around with the right joystick. But when you release the right joystick and keep moving in a direction you will se the camera rotating by it self the align it's direction to where the player is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no input, then find the horizontal rotation the camera would want to go to, then apply a portion of that horizontal rotation to offset (you can use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) for this):

```
void UpdatePosition()
{
    Debug.Log(playerScript.velocity);

    lookHorizontal = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("MouseX") /* + some additional rotation */,
            -10000, 10000);
    lookVertical = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("MouseY") /* + some additional rotation */, 
            -10000, 10000);

    if (lookHorizontal > global.joystickDeadZone 
            || lookHorizontal < -global.joystickDeadZone)
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(lookHorizontal / (1 / global.lookSensitivity * 100),
                Vector3.up) * offset;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector2 flatPlayerVel = playerScript.velocity;

        if (flatPlayervel != Vector2.zero)
        {
            float autoAdjustSpeed = 20f; // find good constant or way to calculate
                                         // For example, could set to 0f for no auto adjust

            // Find horizontal rotation that velocity is trying to go towards 
            Vector2 flatCameraForward = transform.forward;            
            float angleDiff = Vector2.SignedAngle(flatCameraForward, flatPlayerVel);
            Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDiff, Vector3.up);

            // how much to auto move offset horizontally this frame
            Quaternion adjustRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(Quaternion.identity, 
                    goalRotation, autoAdjustSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            offset = adjustRotation * offset;
        }
    }

    if (lookVertical > global.joystickDeadZone || lookVertical < -global.joystickDeadZone)
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(lookVertical / (1 / global.lookSensitivity * 100), 
                -this.transform.right) * offset;
    }
    this.transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(this.transform.position, 
            playerRealPosition + offset, 
            positionLerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Now I have the snake problem where the camera keeps shaking when I go forward or backward, how can I get rid of this ?

Comment: @Trafel does the shaking disappear if you  do something like `if (Math.Abs(angleDiff)>1f) {Quaternion goalRotation  = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDiff, Vector3.up); ... offset = adjustRotation * offset; }` ?